# Регулярное выражение для телефона с необязательным "+"

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, required

Нужно регулярное выражение для телефона, состоящее из любых цифр, включая необязательный + в начале (т.е. чтобы пропускал и без него, но если юзер всетаки его поставит, чтобы форма не ругалась).

как сделать + из этой регулярки не обязательным условием ?

```
\+\d*
```

Comment: `\+?\d*` - квантификатор `?` отвечает 1 или 0 символов

Comment: Но тогда лучше последний квантификатор изменить, иначе регулярка будет отвечать и одному плюсу, и просто пустой строке, без цифр: `\+?\d+`

Answer (score 1):

> как сделать + из этой регулярки не обязательным условием ?

Вопрос после ного поставить - очевидно же.